# Where is info from /proc/dumchar_info used, on MediaTek devices?

Tags: partitions, mediatek

There are plenty of instructions for changing partition layout on Android, including MediaTek devices, and they say I need to edit MBR, EBR and a ‘scatter file’ and to feed the latter to SP Flash or MTKDroidTools. However, [as noted in an answer to “Where does the partition information in /proc/dumchar_info come from, on MTK devices?”](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213717), the MediaTek-specific `/proc/dumchar_info` can't be changed with those means.

Thus the question, where is info from `/proc/dumchar_info` used? And if it doesn't reflect the actual partition layout and doesn't agree with MBR, EBR and the ‘scatter file’ then what effects should I expect?

Comment: Mostly recent devices (with eMMC or UFS) have GPTs. `dumchar_info` is only specific to MTK devices with MBR partitioning scheme (EBRs allow to have 4+ partitions). Since `proc/dumchar_info` isn't a standard interface which AOSP code expects to be there, so it depends on the ROM you are using, whether it's reading partition info from the said file in userspace or not. Neither AOSP requires `/proc/partitions` from Linux kernel to expose necessarily. But programs like `blkid` and `e2fsprpgs` may depend on this.

Comment: However the proper way to update partition table should be to build everything with updated headers; preloader, bootloader (U-Boot/LK), boot kernel, recovery kernel and scatter file to be used later for flashing.